# Compare column A sheet 1 and compare column B sheet 2 and if duplicate found, copy and return value on column B sheet 1 from column C sheet 2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula -

Compare column A sheet 1 and compare column B sheet 2 and if duplicate found, copy and return value on column B sheet 1 from column C sheet 2?

Hope that make sense.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

### A Classic INDEX/MATCH

In e.g. cell `B2` of `Sheet1` use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

and copy down.

It is actually the same as the inferior:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$B:$C,2,FALSE),"")
```

Possibly you want to restrict it to something like

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$101,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$101,0)),"")
```