# How to transfer contents from a excel sheet to send another. Both sheets have relational data but need to transfer the phone number based on same name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, relational-database

The two sheets have similar information but one of the sheets is missing the phone number of the employees. So I need to create a formula that transfers the number over based on both sheets having the same name in the row.

Comment: Index() and match(), many examples exist on here.

Comment: Vlookup, Index/Match, Xlookup all these functions will do that.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71332598) out.